# Should I dispose a BinaryReader if I need to preserve the "wrapped" stream?

Tags: c#, .net, stream, dispose

Both `BinaryReader` [constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.binaryreader%28v=vs.100%29) require a stream parameter. If I need to keep the underlying stream as-is when I'm done with the `BinaryReader`, should I still call its `Dispose()`? If not, is there any other clean-up for the no longer needed `BinaryReader`?

I'm asking because I can't find a clear answer on [MSDN page for `BinaryReader.Dispose()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383354%28v=vs.100%29).

**Small addtion**

In my context I use the `BinaryReader` to read a couple of bytes, after which I set the position of the stream back to what it was before the `BinaryReader` was initialized.

Also, I'm using .Net 4.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it's fine to not dispose of the `BinaryReader` if you want to keep the stream open.

I'd probably add a comment to explain what's going on though - and I'm not sure whether it's *guaranteed* that the `BinaryReader` will have only read from the stream as far as you've read from the `BinaryReader`... it might have read more into a buffer, for example. Obviously that's not a problem if you then seek on the stream.

Comment: yes I updated my question to mention I only read a couple of bytes with the `BinaryReader`.

Answer (score 23):

If you (or anyone else reading these looking for an answer) are using VS 2012 with .NET 4.5 (or later) you can create a `BinaryReader` that won't close the stream.  E.g.:

```
using(var reader = new BinaryReader(theStream, new UTF8Encoding(), true)
{
//...
}
```

`new UTF8Encoding` is the default if you used the BinaryReader(Stream) constructor, if you don't want UTF8Encoding, you can use something else.  The `true` signifies "yes, leave the stream open".

Answer (score 4):

There is already an accepted answer, but it makes me feel dirty :-) I think we can do better:

1. If you're using .NET 4.5, you should use the 3-arg constructor of BinaryReader. Done.
2. If you're using .NET 3.5/4.0, you need a different solution

Jon Skeet (the accepted answer) suggests to just never dispose the BinaryReader. Well, that works ofcourse, but could be a source of confusion.

An alternative solution could be to wrap your Stream in a NonClosingStreamWrapper, before passing that to BinaryReader. The BinaryReader will close the wrapper when it gets disposed, but the NonClosingStreamWrapper will not dispose your underlying Stream. You can still use .Dispose on the binaryStream (or even better, the using-pattern).

Very ironically, @JonSkeet already created a NonClosingStreamWrapper to do just that. It's part of his [miscutil library](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/). (but note the license)

```
using(var reader = new BinaryReader(new NonClosingStreamWrapper(myStream)))
{
//...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it was me, I'd dispose of the BinaryReader, just for the sake of tidyness...but I'd also ensure that I created the `BinaryReader` with this [this constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712804.aspx):

```
public BinaryReader(
  Stream   input,
  Encoding encoding,
  bool     leaveOpen
  )
```

where specifying the `leaveOpen` argument as `true` instructs the reader to leave the underlying stream open.

Going this route, you make explicit the scope and ownership of things. Less room for confusion and misunderstanding that way.

Comment: I agree with your comment 100%, and I would've probably have not asked the question if I was using 4.5 because I would've probably noticed the `leaveOpen` argument.